# How to fetch new branches and switch to them on a forked Git repository?

Tags: git, github

So this Git repository say had 10 branches. I forked it last year. Now this year they added 5 more branches. How can I update my forked repository to show those 5 new branches? Also once I can see those new branches how can I switch between them?

I tried `git checkout origin/newly_added_branchname` but it says

> origin/newly_added_branchname does not appear to be a git repository

Answer (score 1):

You need to *fetch* first, or your local repository will not know there are any changes on the remote, including new branches.

```
$ git fetch
```

Comment: Tried it just now. git fetch followed by git checkout origin/xyz also git checkout master/xyz and git checkout remote/xyz none of them worked.

Comment: @Aditya Those commands make no sense, stop just hammering random things into Git. Seriously, read a tutorial and figure out what the commands actually do instead of just trying everything.

Comment: `git checkout new_branch_name` after doing `git fetch <remote name>` assuming you have your remotes configured correctly.